# A utility to swap two files

Tags: c++, file, file-system

While I have never had to swap two files I have always wondered if there was command for swapping two files and recently I decided to see if there was one. Eventually I found out that there wasn't one and as a result I decided to create one.

Here is the code: `main.cc`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

static auto print_help() -> void {
    std::cout << "Usage: swap [file1] [file2]\n";
    std::cout << "swaps the contents of file1 and file2\n";
    std::cout << "use swap --help to print this message\n";
}

static auto validate_files(const std::filesystem::path& file1_path, const std::filesystem::path& file2_path) -> void {
    {
        /* check if file exists */
        const auto file1_exists = std::filesystem::exists(file1_path);
        const auto file2_exists = std::filesystem::exists(file2_path);
        const auto exists = file1_exists && file2_exists;


        if (!exists) {
            if (!file1_exists) std::cerr << "cannot find file " << file1_path << '\n';
            if (!file2_exists) std::cerr << "cannot find file " << file2_path << '\n';
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    {
        if (file1_path == file2_path) {
            std::cerr << "swaping the same two files does nothing\n";
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}

static auto get_temp_filename(char* template_name) -> void {
    /* tmpnam_s does not work on linux */
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
    errno_t err = tmpnam_s(template_name, L_tmpnam);
    assert(!err);
#else
    int err = mkstemp(template_name);
    assert(err != -1);
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    switch (argc) {
        case 2: {
            /* convert the second arg to upper case */
            std::transform(argv[1],
                argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]),
                argv[1],
                ::toupper);
            if (!strcmp(argv[1], "--HELP")) {
                print_help();
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Invalid args see --help for usage\n";
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        case 3:
            break;
        default: {
            std::cerr << "Invalid args see --help for usage\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    const auto file1_path = std::filesystem::path{ argv[1] };
    const auto file2_path = std::filesystem::path{ argv[2] };


    validate_files(file1_path, file2_path);
    char temp_filename[L_tmpnam] = "XXXXXX";
    get_temp_filename(temp_filename);
    const auto temp_filepath = std::filesystem::path{ temp_filename };
    /* move-swap the files instead of copy-swaping */
    /* renaming a file is the same as moving it */
    std::filesystem::rename(file1_path, temp_filepath);
    std::filesystem::rename(file2_path, file1_path);
    std::filesystem::rename(temp_filepath, file2_path);
}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
swap doc1.txt doc2.txt
```

Comment: What would the expected behavior be if there is a path included in one or both filenames? How would you handle the two files being on different drives? Or if both files are on one file (that is not the current working directory), as the temp file would then be on a different drive?

Comment: I don't know what the behavior would be but what do you do supposed I should do about it?

Comment: Expected `#ifdef RENAME_EXCHANGE renameat2(...) #else` to use the actual system call if possible.

Comment: See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html for  `RENAME_EXCHANGE` to "atomically exchange oldpath and newpath".  Linux is common enough to be worth taking advantage of that feature that's existed since Linux 3.15.

Comment: the Windows version of `std::filesystem::rename` uses https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw with the option `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` which allows for moving files across different drives. However, the Linux version of `std::filesystem::rename` just uses `std::rename` which does not allow moving files across different drives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `file1_path == file2_path` surely tells that paths refer to the same file. However, even if `file1_path != file2_path` they still may refer to the same file.
- `file1_exists = std::filesystem::exists(file1_path);` introduces a TOC-TOU race condition. The file may exist at the time of test, yet disappear by the time of use. See the next bullet.
- `std::filesystem::rename` may fail. You call it tree times. If the second, or third call fails (with an exception!), the filesystem ends up not exactly in a state one would expect. Use a `noexcept` overload, test the `error_code` after each call, and roll back all actions prior to failure. That would also automagically take care of the nonexistent paths.
- Do not `assert`. It is only good to catch bugs, not the runtime problems. In the production code (compiled with `-DNDEBUG`) it does nothing, and your program wouldn't detect an `mkstemp` failure.
- The program silently does nothing if called with, say, 4 arguments. It also takes so much effort if called with 2 arguments. Calling `print_help()` any time `argc != 3` is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the 'question' is asking for code critiques. If I'm wrong about that, please be gentle.. LOL

My first impression is the *readability* of main.
The large argument parsing switch is hiding the more important logic..

Maybe make it easier to read (string objects and case insensitive compares?)..
Even better: relegate to a housekeeping helper method.

(Also: Sometimes *simplistic* is OK. If you don't receive two filename arguments you could immediately spit out the help, rather than telling user to explicitly ask for help.)